# Почему в комментарии нельзя кидать картинки?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, комментарии

Было бы логично, если бы эта привилегия была бы хотя бы у задающего вопрос. Нередко это действительно нужно для выяснения ситуации. Вставлять это в вопрос не всегда уместно, я считаю.

Comment: *Вставлять это в вопрос не всегда уместно, я считаю.* — ы? Любая уточняющая информация должна быть в теле вопроса.

Comment: Иногда нужно скинуть какой-то скрин, который попросил человек из комментов. Он не всегда оказывается полезным, да и в переписке с человеком мне проще скинуть фото в самом сообщении, а не писать "смотри подробнее в Q, я добавил". Особенно это проявляется на Linux stack exchange

Comment: Вы можете ссылки кидать. Или вы хотите именно интерфейс от SO, чтоб можно было при комментировании сразу картинку залит?

Comment: Ненавижу картинки

Comment: @avp в Третьяковку не ходите? :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, надеетесь на мониторе увидеть цвета Куинджи? -)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Комментарии вторичны. Они могут быть удалены в любой момент и кроме модераторов их никто не увидит, даже автор. Таким образом, расширять функционал редактирования комментариев не планируется. Никаких специальных форм для добавления ссылок, картинок или возможности [многострочного текста](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/202356/339911) ждать не стоит.

Если же хочется по-быстрому загрузить и добавить картинку в комментарий, то можно использовать следующее решение:

- В форме ввода ответа на странице, где предполагается писать комментарий, загрузить картинку стандартным способом. В текстовом поле появится ссылка.
- Полученную ссылку на imgur скопировать и вставить в комментарий в формате `[текст ссылки](адрес ссылки)`.

Comment: А зачем их удалять? Удаляет либо автор, либо модер. Автор вряд ли удалит то, что сейчас помогает ему в переписке. Больше скажу - автор может удалить всю инфу из самого вопроса, если захочет! Но, с вашей ссылкой согласен. Однако не очень нравится, когда загоняют в какие-то рамки, которые имеют такое себе основание: дизайн. Красота требует жертв!

Comment: @Miron удаление всей инфы является вандализмом, такую правку откатит любой кто заметит сие действие (не только модер)

Comment: @andreymal это можно применить не только к комментам с картинками.